# Increase the number of sqlite columns and not insert any data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

when the number of columns in My database , for example is 6 , It saves data well. But when I increase the number of columns, for example 10 columns. sqlite not insert any data.There is no error in the program. just not insert data. In the last two weeks I did not get the correct answer. thanks

```
public class Data_par extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "/mnt/sdcard/Par.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Par";

public static final String COL_2 = "ONVAN";
public static final String COL_3 = "TOZIHAT";
public static final String COL_4 = "SAL";
public static final String COL_5 = "MAH";
public static final String COL_6 = "ROOZ";
public static final String COL_7 = "SAL_EKHTAR";
public static final String COL_8 = "MAHE_KHTAR";
public static final String COL_9 = "ROOZ_EKHTAR";
public static final String COL_11 = "SAAT_EKHTAR";
public static final String COL_12 = "DAGHIGHE_EKHTAR";
String DATA_NAME;


public Data_par(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,ONVAN TEXT ,TOZIHAT TEXT ,SAL INTEGER ,MAH INTEGER ,ROOZ INTEGER ,SAL_EKHTAR INTEGER ,MAH_EKHTAR INTEGER ,ROOZ_EKHTAR INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

}


public boolean insertData(String onvan, String tozihat, Integer sal, Integer mah, Integer rooz, Integer sal_ekhtar, Integer mah_ekhtar, Integer rooz_ekhtar) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = Data_par.this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, onvan);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, tozihat);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, sal);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, mah);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, rooz);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, sal_ekhtar);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, mah_ekhtar);
    contentValues.put(COL_9, rooz_ekhtar);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Replace `insert` with `insertOrThrow`.

Comment: its work perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following columns are not present in the insert statement:

```
public static final String COL_8 = "MAHE_KHTAR";
public static final String COL_11 = "SAAT_EKHTAR";
public static final String COL_12 = "DAGHIGHE_EKHTAR";
```

Try adding the needed columns in the insert.

Suggestion for readability:

separate each column definition in a new line and use the variable columns you defined as final.

Example:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                    COL_2  + " TEXT, " +
            + COL_3 + " TEXT) "
```